# Java API: Connect using proxies on different threads

Tags: java, networking, proxy, socks

I would like to use different proxies instead of just one. Currently the [ProxySelector](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ProxySelector.html) sets a system wide proxy for all URLConnections. Does anyone know of a library that supports non system-wide proxies. Just something as simple as adding the appropriate proxy http headers/socks layers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a proxy when [opening a `URLConnection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28java.net.Proxy%29). Is that what you mean?

If you want something that works automatically, you could implement a `ProxySelector` that uses a `ThreadLocal` table internally to provide different selectors based on the calling thread.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection(java.net.Proxy)

It takes http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Proxy.html as an argument.